# Tiny geometrical irregulatities in model imported from Rhino

Tags: export, shaders, geometry

Im migrating an assembly with over 300 parts as .obj to blender to animate it.
Some of the gaps of the rhino geometry get filled with extremly tiny polygons. The resulting surfaces are well connected and dont overlap. The marked gap-filling surface has a width of 0,0001mm:
[image: clean connection]
Yet those surfaces have extreme effects on the shading of the object:
[image]
In the left is a high-poly, in the right a low-poly version. The surface from the first image is still selected, but too small to be seen. Even though the whole surface is really smooth you can see strong shadows.

My question is: What do you think is the most effective way of dealing with such exporting artifacts? 
I know there are many different approaches, like other export options, rebuilding the rhino surface, changing the smoothing of the surface, simplifying the surface etc, but Im new to this program and dont know which is the most elegant way.
Its a bit annoying that such small features have such a big impact. Since I have a lot to export, Im expecting to see this problem over and over again.

Comment: Seems like the mesh has a very irregular topology. Try selecting all the faces in Edit Mode and do "Limited Dissolve".

Comment: Thanks cegaton, that is a good idea. Now I have the problem that the surfaces I want to get rid of are SO small, that they are being ignored by box or brush select. Madness.

Answer (score 1):

If geometry is beyond recovery, but the shape of the object remains intact (like in your case), it can sometimes work to regenerate the object using a combination of the *Remesh* modifier (with as many *levels* your machine can handle), and then using the *Decimate* modifier to simplify the resulting mesh.

In more detail:

1. The *Remesh* modifier will approximate your geometry by fitting it to a grid of voxels and connecting them to reform the mesh - a technique which will only *approximate* your geometry, but can get quite close at high resolutions. The key part here is that once "remeshed", your object will have **uniform detail** everywhere.
2. The high level of detail on the resulting mesh will then need simplification (as big flat surfaces will have been created out of many polygons instead of just one or two), which can be achieved well using techniques posted in other answers to this question: using *Limited dissolve* on the mesh in *Edit mode*, or applying a *Decimate* modifier (which has a few more options, but can accomplish the same result).

Note that this strategy will require you to reapply materials, remake UV maps, seams, sharp edges, etc. and is thus to be used as a **last resort**, or as the **first step** in your workflow if you are going to perform these steps afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just realized that I brought this problem upon myself.
The solution to avoid this problem forever is just entering a "minimal edge length" when exporting.

EDIT: This does not work. There are still surfaces with a width way below the given limit.

Answer (score 0):

that's a common importing problem. 
The easiest solution I found was to remove doubled vertices and to quadrangulate the object. 
In simple steps:
Edit mode > Vertices > select all > Mesh / vertices / remove doubles. 
Then:
Edit mode > Faces > select all > Mesh / faces / tris to quads (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)
This should result in an acceptable mesh object that can be nicely subdivided.
If you need hard edges, try the Edge Split deformer before adding a Subdivide.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience.
In my case it unfortunately doesnt help. The tiny surfaces survive the "remove doubles" as well as the "tris to quads". The result looks even weirder. http://imgur.com/mc5OAyW
Limited dissolve makes it worse as well.
My own solution with the minimum edge length didnt get rid of the tiny surfaces either.

Comment: Another idea: 
select your mesh, choose X > Limited Dissolve and execute Degenerate Dissolve from Mesh > Clean-Up menu. Just an idea though.